# PDF in Python Request

Tags: python, pdf, post, request, response

I have problem with sending a pdf in python post request. My server only supports "form-data" and not JSON

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import os
import json

url = "myUrl"
files ={'fileUpload': open(os.path.join('_my_path', 'my_file.pdf'), 'rb')}
payload = "--my_boundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"integrationClass\"\r\n\r\nBPMOnline\r\n--my_boundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"SITE\"\r\n\r\n21218\r\n--my_boundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"PROCESS_NAME\"\r\n\r\ncreate\r\n--my_boundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"DOCUMENT_ID\"\r\n\r\ndoc bpmonline create\r\n--my_boundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"DOCUMENT_TYPE\"\r\n\r\nsample\r\n--my_boundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CLIENT_NAME\"\r\n\r\ncname\r\n--my_boundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"CLIENT_ID\"\r\n\r\n45678\r\n--my_boundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"USER\"\r\n\r\nadmin\r\n--my_boundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileUpload\"; filename=\"download.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n\r\n--my_boundary\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uuid\"\r\n\r\n\r\n--my_boundary--"
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=my_boundary",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }

response = requests.post(url, data=payload,files=files, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

ERROR is: `"ValueError: Data must not be a string."`

Comment: The `data=` parameter is meant for other form fields such as `<input name="test">` would be `data = {'test' : 'something'}`. And it expects the format to be a dictionary, not a string. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file I have no idea on how to actually manually define the boundaries *(used for file uploads)*, those are usually created by the request module automatically. You're half way in to creating a manually structured POST request but also half way into the automated process if the request module.

Comment: Did you had a look at [requests toolbelt](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uploading-data.html#uploading-data) to upload multipart data ?

Comment: Yes @MauriceMeyer, i use Fiddler, and i can see all parameter in the request.

Comment: @Torxed i have half solution :D i can send pdf and appropriate parameters but i can not see them on the website, and it is really problem for me..parameters have boundary I set myself in the payload variable  but pdf has boundary I set and different random boundary..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can send both data and files in a multipart encoded file, so you can try making your data a "file" too. Something like this:

```
files = {
'data' : data,
'document': open('file_name.pdf', 'rb')
}

headers = {
'Accept': "multipart/form-data",
'Content-Type': "application/pdf",
'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank youu, in Fiddler i can see that works(pdf was sent in form-data) buut, somewhere i have to define 'content-type' : "application/pdf" because on the site pdf can't be opened..Have you any idea?

Comment: Add the stuff as a header and send it accordingly. Update: Check the updated answer. :)

Comment: problem is solved, than you very much but there is new problem :D now, my form data looks like: ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
--ea199251f2fea188a655f0e79b64c5d8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload"; filename="download.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.5
%    .......    i have new number under my boundary (--ea199251f2fea188a655f0e79b64c5d8) and it doesn t work and my server can t recieve this pdf  :(

Comment: Ok,thanks..You're so nice and you helped..Thank you very much..I will try on some other server :)